# Debian Linux installation cannot play sound

Tags: debian, audio

I am trying to get my Linux installation to play musix. I have debian Linux. The contents of /etc/debian_version are:
6.0.2
I cannot seem to get any sound to play from my speakers and after looking through forum postings, I have hit a brick wall.
`lspci | grep Audio` gives the following:

```
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Creative Labs [SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio] CA0110-IBG PCI to PCIe Bridge
03:00.0 Audio device: Creative Labs [SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio] CA0110-IBG
0a:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Cypress HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5800 Series]
```

When I attempt to run the speaker-test command I the following error:

```
Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy
```

So I look for the process which might be blocking the soundcard: `lsof | grep snd` (command taken from some forum). Once the process has been killed, I get the following error:

```
Write error: -5,Input/output error
xrun_recovery failed: -5,Input/output error
Transfer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Note, the process that I kill probably should not be killed.

Comment: post the output of `lsmod | grep snd` and `lsof | grep snd`

Answer (score 1):

Post the output of:
1. `lsmod | grep snd`
2. `cat /proc/asound/cards`
3. `aplay -L`
4. try to play sound like this `aplay -D hw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`
5. `groups | grep audio`

BTW, there is a good description of alsa [here](http://alsa.opensrc.org/.asoundrc)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and i fixed installing the Pulseaudio packages.

You could try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Please expand your answer.